# Stepping over code in Chrome JavaScript debugger throws an exception for a different line?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm attempting to step through the following JavaScript code in Chrome developer tools:
[image: Chrome Debugger]

I can single-step over each function starting after the breakpoint on line 99. Interestingly, if I attempt to single-step over line 101, it steps over both line 101 *and* 102.

However, when I attempt to step over line 103, the code throws the following exception:

```
obj.TcpPortEx is not a function
```

I don't see how that has anything to do with line 103. I could see how line 118 might throw that exception, but we haven't gotten there yet. It feels like Chrome is performing out-of-order execution--it doesn't do that while debugging, does it?

---

Edit:

Here's a comparison of the .asp file on disk (on the server) with what's delivered over the wire:

[image: comparison]

The .asp on disk has `show()` defined at line 81 while the .asp on the wire has it at line 96. Likewise, line 103 in the on-disk .asp is:

```
obj.TcpPortEx(tcpPort, tcpUpnpPort);
```

Line 103 in the over-the-wire .asp is:

```
var tcpUpnpPort = document.getElementsByName('portTcpUpnp')[0].value;
```

What confuses me is how Chrome is using line numbers from the .asp prior to it being processed by the server--it doesn't even have access to that file, does it?

Comment: Notice that the error is indicating that `show` is defined on line 103 when your code shows it defined on line 96 instead. There is a disparity between what the debugger is showing and what the source appears to be. Possibly a cache issue.

Comment: I tried checking the "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)" option, quit Chrome, opened it open, started Developer Tools, and then went to the site in question. I still get the exact same behavior. I think this page is provided by an ASP script--not sure if that makes a difference.